# Visual studio refactoring a property of a viewmodel does not reflect in the View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, refactoring, resharper

I have a simple ViewModel class like

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public String Information { get; set; }
}
```

My View inherits from it and I got Intellisense kicking in. So far so good.

I have written these for tests in the View:

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.Information) %>
-- <%= Html.Label("Information") %>
-- <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Information) %>
-- <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Information) %>
```

I simply rename the property Information to Information2 and let Visual Studio, or Resharper 5, do its magic. However what I experience is that none of the *properties* in the View get adjusted resulting in none functioning code.

I was under the impression that refactoring would also update the view(s)? Am I doing something wrong or turned off some checkbox by accident in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. Good suggestion but unfortunately no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works on my machine!  ;)

It think the correct answer is:
http://www.jetbrains.com/support/resharper/

Comment: Hmm, even the ultimate thing to do, reboot completely, didn't work.

Comment: I contacted Resharper support. Hopefully they can help me out.